# Cast a PHP array into a user object?

Tags: php, object, casting

I have an array which I retrieve from some other source. This array then needs to be casted into a custom class I've created.

The reason I can't use stdObject, is because my class has a custom `__get` as well as a number of convinience methods.

I basically need something like this:

```
$obj = (MyClass) $array;
```

Which does not look possible, it causes a syntax error.

Comment: Interesting question! This may be impossible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make a constructor that takes an array and constructs the object out of that array.

Comment: the "constructing" can be done quickly http://stackoverflow.com/a/1869147/3779853

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you could achieve it with `MyClass::__set_state($array)`

Comment: @nwinkler: Sure it does. Check the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.set-state

Answer (score 3):

Theres a way which I have used before but is more of an hack, you can cast the array to an stdclass then serialize it into a string, then using string manipulation change the class name and then un-serialize the object:

```
function ClassCaster($class, $object)
{
    return unserialize(preg_replace('/^O:\d+:"[^"]++"/', 'O:' . strlen($class) . ':"' . $class . '"', serialize($object)));
}

class SampleClass
{
    public function __wakeup(){ /*Generic wake up from serialization */}
}

$array = array(/* ... */);
$SampleClass = ClassCaster("SampleClass",(object)$array);
```

This is not a pretty method but i believe its the only hack about.

Comment: Wasn't me. I've upvoted :) The solution is too much of a hack though.

Comment: Yea, but at-least its a possibility, and thank you for the vote