# Wrong values from array

Tags: php, arrays, web-services, json

I'm getting wrong values from array.

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://onleague.stormrise.pt:8031/OnLeagueRest/resources/onleague/Utils/Countries');
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
$countries = array(); 
foreach($data['data'] as $item) {
    $countries[] = $item['description'];
}
print_r($countries);
```

the results are:

```
Array ( [0] => g [1] => )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not traversing the object correctly.

```
foreach($data['data']['item'] as $item) {
    $countries[] = $item['description'];
}
```

---

It might help if you view the data with some white space.

```
{
    "valid": true,
    "id": "0",
    "data": {
        "@type": "genericObjectArray",
        "item": [
            {"id": "DE", "description": "Deutschland"},
            {"id": "ES", "description": "España"},
            {"id": "FR", "description": "France"},
            {"id": "PT", "description": "Portugal"},
            {"id": "UK", "description": "United Kingdom"},
            {"id": "US", "description": "United States"}
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: how can I add "id" values to my array?

Comment: Yours suggestion '$countries[] = $item;' gives me this:
Array
Array
Array
Array
Array

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem so crazy than print an array by print_r getting a value on a position and getting that value by index getting another (a value that print_r show in another position) it helped me a lot: [How to convert an array to object in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869091/convert-array-to-object-php/1869147#1869147).
I created a stdClass like another answer on same question of link above and iterated puting values on

```
 $obj->"X".index = value
```

getting something like

```
 $obj->p1,$obj->p2,...
```

with values, after used it to fill my real obj like

```
 $realobj1->myprop1 = $obj2->p1...
```

Its nasty but solved my problem