# From Real stdClass Object to Mock

Tags: php, mocking, stdclass

I have a Soap WebService that returns StdClass Object with different properties. What i want to do is to create a Mock Object that simulates the StdClass returned by WebService. What i dont want to do is to create the mock object manually. I dont want to serialize, unserialize the object because i want to maybe edit propertie values inside VCS.

So basically i need to turn this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [paramA] => 1
    [paramB] => 2
    [paramC] => 3
    [paramD] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [paramD1] => 'blabla'
                [paramD2] => 'blabla'
```

into this:

```
$object = new stdClass;
$object -> paramA = 1;
$object -> paramB = 2;
$object -> paramC = 3;
$object -> paramD -> paramD1 = "blabla";
$object -> paramD -> paramD2 = "blabla";
```

How would you do it?

Answer (score 1):

A good way to quickly build stdClass objects is to cast an array to an object (outlined in [*Type Juggling*](http://php.net/language.types.type-juggling)):

```
$object = (object) array('prop' => 'value');
```

and as this shows, keys become property names and the values their values:

```
echo $object->prop; # value
```

This also works inside each other, like having an array of child objects:

```
$object = (object) array(
    'prop'     => 'value',
    'children' => array(
        (object) array('prop' => 'value'),
    ),
);
```

Which will give you something along the lines like:

```
echo $object->children[0]->prop; # value
```

Which looks like that this is what you're looking for.

See as well [Convert Array to Object PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1869091/367456) for some more examples and variations.

Comment: Sorry, not really what i want. I want to "parse" object one time and save the output as object definition.

Comment: You might be looking for something called serialization: http://php.net/language.oop5.serialization

Comment: "I dont want to serialize, unserialize the object because i want to maybe edit propertie values inside VCS." or do you have any ideas how i can turn serialized object into object definition?

Comment: Uhm, well, serialzation is for storing. So to say to put an object "off-line" (program not running) and back online again. If you also need to edit the serialized format - you write VCS - you probably mean by using a text-editor? Because objects serialized with `serialize()` can just be edited as well with a PHP script that is unserializing them, modifying the online object and serializing again. Another way in PHP that is similar simple to serialize/unserialize is to use `var_export` to write and `include` with the `return` statement to pull it back in. You save a PHP file you can edit then.

Comment: An example of that is here: http://blog.elijaa.org/index.php?post/2010/06/22/Handle-configuration-in-PHP-with-var_export() - just you can probably better understand what I just commented about `var_export`.