# PHP Template - Using extract() and access vars by object. Array is given

Tags: php, arrays, object, foreach, extract

I want something like this in my template file:

```
<ul>
<?foreach($friends as $var):?>

        <li>
            <?=$var->name?>
        </li>

<?endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

I use this in my model.php:

```
$data = array('friends' => array(
    array('name' => 'testname'),
    array('name' => 'testname2')
));

// missing code here ?

extract($data, EXTR_SKIP);
include('template_file.html');
```

How can I use $var->name to access 'name' as an object in my template file?

$data = array() is set.

Update:

Its because, I dont want to use  `<?=$var['name']?>` in my template.

Comment: `<?php echo $var['name']; ?>`
?

Comment: try `array_walk($data['friends'], function(&$v){ $v = (object)$v; });` before `extract()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
<?
foreach($data as $eachData)
{
 foreach($eachData as $var):?>
  {

        <li>
            <?php echo $var->name?>
        </li>

<?php 
  }
} ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$var->name` : this is way to get the valus in object.

In arrays to get values use it like this : `$var['name']`

To convert arrays to object refer this : [How to convert an array to object in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869091/convert-array-to-object-php)

Answer (score 0):

Considering this:

```
$data = array('friends' => array(
    array('name' => 'testname'),
    array('name' => 'testname2')
));

<?foreach($data['friends'] as $var):?>
    <li>
        <!-- $var will be testname2 -->
        <?=$var; ?>
    </li>
<?endforeach ?>

<?foreach($data['friends'] as $key => $var):?>
    <li>
        <!-- $var will be testname2, $key will be "name" -->
        <?=$var; ?>
    </li>
<?endforeach ?>
```

You should overthink your naming of your array keys. There must be a new key for every value or you will overwrite the previous setted value.