# converting array to stdClass in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am returning data from two tables in CodeIgniter with the function below

```
public function test()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('WHOUSE1.DLY_BWR_DLY_PERFORMANCE');
    $this->db->join('WHOUSE1.DATE_DIM', 'WHOUSE1.DATE_DIM.DATE_KEY = WHOUSE1.DLY_BWR_DLY_PERFORMANCE.BDP_DATE');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

**Using var_dump I am getting the result below**

```
array (size=3226)
0 => 
array (size=121)
  'BDP_ID' => string '945149' (length=6)
  'BDP_COST_CENTRE_NUMBER' => string '1376' (length=4)
  'BDP_DATE' => string '20040807' (length=8)
  'BDP_DAY_CODE' => string '6' (length=1)
  'BDP_TAKE' => string '4923.78' (length=7)
  'BDP_PAYOUT' => string '3779.22' (length=7)
  'BDP_ACTUAL_SLIPPAGE' => string '636' (length=3)

1 => 
array (size=121)
  'BDP_ID' => string '945150' (length=6)
  'BDP_COST_CENTRE_NUMBER' => string '1376' (length=4)
  'BDP_DATE' => string '20040809' (length=8)
  'BDP_DAY_CODE' => string '1' (length=1)
  'BDP_TAKE' => string '2848.3' (length=6)
  'BDP_PAYOUT' => string '4190.34' (length=7)
  'BDP_ACTUAL_SLIPPAGE' => string '280' (length=3)
```

**But what I will like to get is this**

```
  array (size=3226)
  0 => 
  object(stdClass)[27]
  'BDP_ID' => string '945149' (length=6)
  'BDP_COST_CENTRE_NUMBER' => string '1376' (length=4)
  'BDP_DATE' => string '20040807' (length=8)
  'BDP_DAY_CODE' => string '6' (length=1)
  'BDP_TAKE' => string '4923.78' (length=7)
  'BDP_PAYOUT' => string '3779.22' (length=7)
  'BDP_ACTUAL_SLIPPAGE' => string '636' (length=3)

  1 => 
  object(stdClass)[29]
  'BDP_ID' => string '945150' (length=6)
  'BDP_COST_CENTRE_NUMBER' => string '1376' (length=4)
  'BDP_DATE' => string '20040809' (length=8)
  'BDP_DAY_CODE' => string '1' (length=1)
  'BDP_TAKE' => string '2848.3' (length=6)
  'BDP_PAYOUT' => string '4190.34' (length=7)
  'BDP_ACTUAL_SLIPPAGE' => string '280' (length=3)
```

I can't seem to get a way of converting the array into object(stdClass) Any help will be appreciated as am new to CodeIgniter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert an array to object in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869091/how-to-convert-an-array-to-object-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
return $query->result();
```

This function returns the query result as an array of objects, or an empty array on failure. Typically you'll use this in a foreach loop, like this:

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
   echo $row->title;
   echo $row->name;
   echo $row->body;
}
```

**Edit:**

If you just want to print you can use `var_dump()` or `print_r()`.

```
var_dump($obj);
print_r($obj);
```

If you want an array of all properties and their values use `get_object_vars()`.

```
$properties = get_object_vars($obj);
print_r($properties);
```

Comment: The function is fails when I use $query->result(); Is there anything else I can do? Thank you.

Comment: I am getting a blank screen, no error is display even though  my Apache environment is set to display all error.

Answer (score 1):

Array to stdClass can be done in php this way.

```
stdClass:: __set_state(array());
```

Or a nicer way.

```
$a = (object) array();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in Your Model ( change your table name and select, distinct fileds )

```
        $this->db->select('DISTINCT(subcategory)');
        $this->db->from('tbl_property');  
        $this->db->where('status','1');                          
        $data           = $this->db->get()->result(); 
        $sub_id         = array();
        foreach ($data as $row)
        {
            array_push($sub_id,$row->subcategory);
        }
        $this->db->from('tbl_subcategory');  
        $this->db->where_in('id',$sub_id);                          
        $data1          = $this->db->get()->result();
        return $data1;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the same documentation for Codeigniter I detail:

```
result_array()

This function returns the query result as a pure array, or an empty array when no 
result `is produced. Typically you'll use this in a foreach loop, like this:`
```

and ..

```
result()

This function returns the query result as an array of objects, or an empty array 
on failure.
```

You should return your data in this way

```
return $query->result();
```

Comment: Hi John, my function fails using $query->result(); Is there a way to re-write function test() so as not to fail. I only use result_array(); to pull out data so I can explain what I wanted to do

Comment: Look, public function test()
{
    $this->db->join('WHOUSE1.DATE_DIM', 'WHOUSE1.DATE_DIM.DATE_KEY = WHOUSE1.DLY_BWR_DLY_PERFORMANCE.BDP_DATE');
    return $this->db->get('WHOUSE1.DLY_BWR_DLY_PERFORMANCE')->result();
}

Comment: Well, still the same. But can't understand why you voted me down when you couldn't even help. No offense meant.

Comment: because, the answer comes in codeigniter manual, although I did not vote negative to your question :(