# Convert array to object class in php

Tags: php

i have array look like this:

```
$config = array(
   'id' => 123,
   'name' => 'bla bla',
   'profile' => array(
      'job' => 'coder',
      'more' => 'info'
   )
);
```

i want to create class Config look like this:

```
$c = new Config($config);

echo $c->profile->more;
```

somebody can help me?

Comment: Look at the following post. Hope you will get your answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869091/convert-array-to-object-php

Comment: `$c = (object)$config;`

Comment: echo $c->id is working but echo $c->profile->more not working, this error:  Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Because what @AntonGildebrand said works only for flat arrays and there is nesting in yours (see my answer below).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the constructor of your Config class:

```
$object = json_decode(json_encode($array), false);
```

In general, if your array is flat (no nesting), then you could also use:

```
$object = (object)$array;
```

Answer (score 0):

On class construct create config objects from array.
If you want more then look at __set() __get() __call() class functions.

Working code:

```
$config = array(
   'id' => 123,
   'name' => 'bla bla',
   'profile' => array(
      'job' => 'coder',
      'more' => 'info'
   )
);

class Config{
    public function __construct($data){
        foreach($data as $k => $v){
            $this->{$k} = (object)$v;
        }
    }



}


$c = new Config($config);

print_r($c);

echo $c->profile->job;
```

Response:

```
Config Object
(
    [id] => stdClass Object
        (
            [scalar] => 123
        )

    [name] => stdClass Object
        (
            [scalar] => bla bla
        )

    [profile] => stdClass Object
        (
            [job] => coder
            [more] => info
        )

)
coder
```