# PHP: How to extract a property from this array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of values returned from Facebook - let's call it `$array`.

If I do `print_r($array)` - it looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [code] => 200
    [headers] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Some value
                    [value] => *
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Some value
                    [value] => Some value
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Some value
                    [value] => Some value
                )


        )

    [body] => {"about":"Some more values.","can_post":true}
)
```

I need to extract the `body` part from this array.

I cannot refer to it by it's position, I'm looking for something like `$array->body` and receive the `{....}` string.

Comment: `->` is for objects, you have array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$array->body` would work if the variable `$array` was an object

For arrays, just use:

```
$body = $array['body'];
```

(see: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access to your array via `->` just do 1 more step:

```
$array = (object) $array;
```

And now, you can access to your body via:

```
$array->body;
```

Else without this step there is just one way:

```
$array['body'];
```

---

If you are more interested about converting arrays into objects, you can visit this question: [How to convert an array to object in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869091/convert-array-to-object-php)

Answer (score 1):

Access array elements by using their name.

```
$array['body'];
```