# How create object PHP?

Tags: php

There is a object from function `result():`

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
   echo $row->title;
   echo $row->name;
   echo $row->body;
}
```

How I can get the same object from the next array:

```
$arr[$key] = array(
     'Reason' => $status,
     'Time'   => $val->time,
      'IdUser' => $val->dot,
       'Date'   => $val->date,
        'IdUser' => $val->IdUser,
          'Photo'  => $val->Photo
);
```

I tried `(object)$arr`

Comment: Duplicate question. Answer here: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869091/convert-array-to-object-php`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Array to Object PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869091/convert-array-to-object-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `$key` being a string, it's pretty easy, just cast to object both:

```
$key = 'test';
$arr[$key] = (object)array(
     'Reason' => 1,
     'Time'   => 100,
      'IdUser' => $val->dot,
       'Date'   => $val->date,
        'IdUser' => $val->IdUser,
          'Photo'  => $val->Photo
);
$row = (object)$arr;

var_dump($row->test);
/*
object(stdClass)#1 (5) {
  ["Reason"]=>
  int(1)
  ["Time"]=>
  int(100)
  ["IdUser"]=>
  NULL
  ["Date"]=>
  NULL
  ["Photo"]=>
  NULL
}
*/
echo $row->test->Time; //100
```

If `$key` is a number...you're out of luck. In some php versions, `$row->{'2'}`, for instance, would work, but mainly it won't - and if you want to use a numerical index as object property you're making some design mistake somewhere. See this codepad for the source of my example: http://codepad.org/Y7F2xCnj

Answer (score 1):

You have a good example on http://php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.php

```
$obj = (object) array('foo' => 'bar', 'property' => 'value');

echo $obj->foo; // prints 'bar'
echo $obj->property; // prints 'value'
```

Your associative array is converted in an object and you can get his properties now.

There are anothers ways to convert an array to object, take the best solution for you:

[How to convert an array to object in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869091/convert-array-to-object-php)