# How to Change Array Structure in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have an array in the following form,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [emailAddress] => abc@gmail.com
            [subject] => Hi
            [content] => How are you?
            [attachment] => QmFzZTY0IGlzIGFuIGVuY29kaW5nIHNjaGVtZSB1c2VkIHRvIHJlcHJlc2VudCBiaW5hcnkgZGF0YSBpbiBhbiBBU0NJSSBmb3JtYXQuIA==
            [fileName] => Base 64 Encoder
        )
)
```

How could I have it on the following form:

```
Array
(
    [emailAddress] => abc@gmail.com
    [subject] => Hi
    [content] => How are you?
    [attachments] => Array
        (
            [attachment] => QmFzZTY0IGlzIGFuIGVuY29kaW5nIHNjaGVtZSB1c2VkIHRvIHJlcHJlc2VudCBiaW5hcnkgZGF0YSBpbiBhbiBBU0NJSSBmb3JtYXQu
            [fileName] => Base 64 Encoder
        )

)
```

And is there any way to convert the type of `[attachments] => Array` to `[attachments] => Object`? like below:

```
Array
(
    [emailAddress] => abc@gmail.com
    [subject] => Hi
    [content] => How are you?
    [attachments] => Object
        (
            [attachment] => QmFzZTY0IGlzIGFuIGVuY29kaW5nIHNjaGVtZSB1c2VkIHRvIHJlcHJlc2VudCBiaW5hcnkgZGF0YSBpbiBhbiBBU0NJSSBmb3JtYXQu
            [fileName] => Base 64 Encoder
        )

)
```

I've tried to look number of methods (like array_push, array_splice and etc.) but still can't get it. Hope someone can help me with that. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to change the array AFTER it's build or change the way it's build the first time?

Comment: Regarding your 2nd question (array => object), please check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1869147/3647441

Comment: I want to change it after it's build. Because the original array is retrieved from the excel file.

Comment: `$array[0]` ? If you want to generate it that way, then paste how this was generated.

Comment: @Jigar, I have retrieved the original array from the excel file, that is why it looks like that.

Comment: Thanks @mario.klump, will look into it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
$result = array();
$result = $arr[0];
$result['attachments'] = new stdClass();
$result['attachments']->attachment = $result['attachment'];
$result['attachments']->fileName = $result['fileName'];
unset($result['attachment']);
print_r($result);
```