# Array to object conversion

Tags: php, arrays

My query returns an array, but i need an object with that array in it.

In example my array:

```
Array(
    "key1" => "value1",
    "key2" => "value2",
    "key3" => "value3"
);
```

So what I am trying to do is to create a \StdClass and add this array in it. Ideally i would like the end product to look like this:

```
object(stdClass) {"test"=>array(1) {object(stdClass)(3) {"key1" => "value1", "key2" => "value2", "key3" => "value3"}} }
```

I created a function arrayToObject:

```
public function arrayToObject(array $array)
{
    $test = new \StdClass($array);

    return $test;
}
```

This does not work creates an object but my array is not is in.

How can I achieve what I am trying to do....?

Comment: This question has already been asked, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1869147/5236312).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\stdClass` doesn't have a constructor that accepts an array as an argument. You can add the array explicitly as a property. Try:

```
function arrayToObject(array $array, $property = 'myArrayProperty')
{
    $test = new \StdClass($array);
    $test->{$property} = $array;

    return $test;
}

$arr = ['foo' => 1, 'bar' => 2];
$obj = arrayToObject($arr);

// `echo $obj->myArrayProperty['foo']` => 1

print_r($obj)
```

This yields:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [myArrayProperty] => Array
        (
            [foo] => 1
            [bar] => 2
        )

)
```

Unless you want to actually convert the array into an object, (which is more useful in my view) where the array keys become the object properties. In which case you can perform a direct cast:

```
$arr = [
    'key1' => 'value1',
    'key2' => 'value2',
    'key3' => 'value3'
];

$obj = (object) $arr;

print_r($obj);
```

Yields:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [key1] => value1
    [key2] => value2
    [key3] => value2
)
```

Access via:

```
echo $obj->key1; // 'value1'
```

Hope this helps :)

**EDIT**

I had a closer look at the example output you want. You want to create a `\stdClass` object, with a `test` property. This is an array containing one element: a nested `\stdClass` object containing properties and values from the array.

Are you looking for something like this?

```
$arr = [
    'key1' => 'value1', 
    'key2' => 'value2', 
    'key3' => 'value3'
];

$obj = new \stdClass();
$obj->test = [(object) $arr];

var_dump($obj);
```

Yields:

```
class stdClass#1 (1) {
  public $test =>
  array(1) {
    [0] =>
    class stdClass#2 (3) {
      public $key1 =>
      string(6) "value1"
      public $key2 =>
      string(6) "value2"
      public $key3 =>
      string(6) "value3"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thx this has almost done the trick now I have:  `object(stdClass) {"key"=>array(3) { "key1"=>"value1 etc.}}` what is missing is: object(stdClass) {"key"=>array(3) }

Comment: Ah... I didn't really look very hard at the example output you wanted. Updated my answer there.

Comment: Hey thank you so much this works exacly how i expected happy days :)

Comment: No problem, glad to assist :)

Comment: Would up vote your answer as well but apparently I dont have enough points :o

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using (that's most clean solutio, I think):

```
$obj = json_decode(json_encode($array), FALSE);
```

Another solution would be to create empty `stdClass`, walktrough it (using `foreach`) and fill it with array data.

```
public function arrayToObject(array $array)
{
    $test = new \StdClass($array);
    foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    {
        $test->$key = $value;
    }
    return $test;
}
```

Comment: hey but I also need 1 key in this object with the values of my Array

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `foreach` and CAST it to `object`

```
$Object = [];

foreach($array as $key => $val){
  $Object[$key] = (object)$val;
}
print_r($Object);
```