# creating object from array in php

Tags: php, arrays, api

I need to be able to create an object from an array. The data is coming from a terrible API. Here is an example of the data.

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [no] => 1
        [FL] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [content] => 1505250000001141005
                        [val] => ACCOUNTID
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [content] => 1505250000000091001
                        [val] => SMOWNERID
                    )

                [2] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [content] => name here
                        [val] => Account Owner
                    )
ETC...
```

The [no] value is insignificant. the [FL] content is everything I need in the object.
So the outcome I would like is all of the values will be variable names and content will be the values. Can anyone suggestion anything to help please?

***EDIT***
I think I need to clarify what I need. I'm creating a class called Account which will hold all the information from the api call in an object. I will instantiate the object then call a method for example valuesFromArray() and pass it the [FL] array given by the api call. it will use [val] as the variable name and [content] as its value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert an array to object in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869091/how-to-convert-an-array-to-object-in-php)

Comment: Is this decoded JSON?

Comment: What method did you use get api ? Curl or fil_get_content method.

Comment: I used curl to grab the data and yes its Json decoded.

Comment: To clarify, you want the result as `$ACCOUNTID="1505250000001141005"; $SHOWNERID="1505250000000091001"; ${'Account Owner'}="name here";` ? Or should "ACCOUNTID" etc. be object properties? Or keys in a new array?

Comment: Yes the first option.

Answer (score 0):

```
     $json_url = "API URL";
    //  Initiate curl
    $ch_curl = curl_init();
    // Disable SSL verification
    curl_setopt($ch_curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    // Will return the response, if false it print the response
    curl_setopt($ch_curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    // Set the url
    curl_setopt($ch_curl, CURLOPT_URL, $json_url);
    // Execute
    $result = curl_exec($ch_curl);
    // Closing
    curl_close($ch_curl);
    $data = json_decode($result, true);//true--> Convert object to array format
```

This is the curl method to fetch data from API.Use `json_decode($result, true)` use json decode convert object to array format.

I hope this is usefull for your question.

Please review,

Thanks!