# Convert Array To An Object In PHP

Tags: php

I have an array that looks like this.

```
$data['id'][0] = 123;
$data['id'][1] = 302;
```

....
And so on, I have to convert this to an object like this,

```
$object = ['id' => [123, 302.....]];
```

I can't seem to achieve this in a way like this

```
$object = (object)$data;
```

How can I do this in PHP? What's the most efficient way of doing it. Thanks

Comment: there are many ways to do that, `json_decode(json_encode(..))`, using new arr with stdClass

Comment: [helpful link](https://www.phpro.org/examples/Convert-Object-To-Array-With-PHP.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert an array to object in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869091/how-to-convert-an-array-to-object-in-php)

Comment: What you mean by `$object = ['id' => [123, 302.....]];`??? See the example: [https://3v4l.org/eFFl3](https://3v4l.org/eFFl3)

Answer (score 0):

create the object class like so:

```
class myObject {
  public $myArray;

  public function __construct($myArray = array()) {
     foreach ($myArray as $value)
     {
        $this->myArray[] = $value;
     }
  }

}
```

And when you initiate a new object, you'll be able to pass the values like so:

```
$newArray = new myObject($data['id']);
```

Then if you wanted to see what is inside your array, just do:

```
foreach ($newArray->myArray as $value)
{
  echo "{$value}<br>";
}
```