# Laravel Eloquent nullable fields value converted to string "NULL"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have in my model a query to get data from the database and there are nullable fields present in my database table. When I try to display all the records in my view, the fields which are of null value, is displayed as "NULL". I want these values to be display as just empty string.

Here is what I have in my controller:

```
public function showDetails($action, $id)
{
        $data_model= new PersonData();
        $persons= $data_model->loadSpecificPerson($id);

        return view('pages.admin.reporting_person_details', ['action' => $action, 'id' => $id])->with('id', $id)->with(compact('persons'));
}
```

In my model:

```
public function loadSpecificPerson($id)
{
        $persons = DB::select("SELECT * FROM complainant_t WHERE ComplainantID = ?", [$id]);
        return $persons;
}
```

I wanted to do it like how you would do it in an array:

```
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
   if($array[$key] == NULL)
   {
        $array[$key] = "";
   }
}
```

This isn't possible to use with $persons since it's an object and must be accessed with name right? So how should I perform this without having to access it by the column names?

Comment: Are you sure the value is NULL and not 'NULL` in your DB? Two different things

Comment: `$result = DB::select($sql)->get();
$result = $result->toArray();` it will convert your object to an array

Comment: Supposedly, when it is NULL, it won't show anything

Comment: @geckob in my Database, NULL is the default value.

Comment: @FriencyFernandez You figured out

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm not the one who made the DB, I've just realized the problem is because the field values are "NULL" (string). I've modified it to be NULL and it is working fine now without having to convert it to empty string.

Comment: Exactly. A lot of people confused about this

Comment: @geckob Yes it was a silly mistake and I did not realize it until I looked at the database. Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

Basically `NULL` field is always displayed `''` empty string.
But if not then you can achieve as below.

```
foreach($persons as $person){
    //consider you want to display here
    //Please check it's NULL or 'NULL'
    echo $person->field === NULL ? '' : $person->field;
}
```

Here basically it will check all fields, If field is `NULL` then it will display `''` empty string else it will display original value.

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Hi do I have to specify field?

Comment: change `field` according to  your database `column name`

Answer (score 0):

Use is_null or === operator.

- is_null($result['column'])
- $result['column'] === NULL

In Laravel, you can read about `toArray()' that will convert object to array and later you can use normal logic. Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections

In Model

```
   return $persons->toArray();
```

Logic

```
$object = new stdClass();
foreach($array as $key => $value)
{
    $array[$key] = is_null($value) ? '' : $value;
    $object->$key = is_null($value) ? '' : $value;
}
```

If you want to use object then use `$object` variable else `$array` as array

Comment: If i convert it to array I'd have to use array for my blade instead of object right?

Comment: Yes....and if you want to use object only in blade then convert to array and manipulate the values and again convert to object...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869091/how-to-convert-an-array-to-object-in-php

Comment: I don't know why but it shows an error
Call to a member function toArray() on array

Comment: Please refer laravel collections link to the usage of toArray function...

Comment: There was a mistake in the database. MYSQL set the default expression as "NULL" which causes the problem. Thank you for your answer though it works also :)