# How to convert array of arrays into object in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, casting

I have an array of arrays like this one below and I want to convert it to object array.

```
array (size=3)
  'declaration' => 
    array (size=99)
      'GO_IMPZONK_ID' => string '130334' (length=6)
      'ID' => string '19802862' (length=8)
      'CUSTE' => string '10100' (length=5)
      'DCLEXP' => null
      'DCL_BROKER_CODE' => string '' (length=0)
      'RLCCODE' => string '' (length=0)
  'items' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=50)
          'GO_IMPDCL_ID' => string '19802862' (length=8)
          'TARIFYEAR' => string '85' (length=2)
  'extensions' => 
    array (size=6)
      0 => 
        array (size=5)
          'GO_IMPDCL_ID' => string '19802862' (length=8)
          'TOTVALUE' => string '0.00' (length=4)
          'EXPDATE' => string '2004-03-20' (length=10)
      1 => 
        array (size=5)
          'GO_IMPDCL_ID' => string '19802862' (length=8)
          'TOTVALUE' => string '0.00' (length=4)
          'EXPDATE' => string '2004-03-20' (length=10)
```

I did try casting it like this but it only makes Object with arrays inside.

```
$obj=(object)$array;
```

what can i do to have nesting multi level Objects from my array?

Comment: You could try `$arr = json_decode(json_encode($arr));` ?

Comment: $obj = json_decode(json_encode($array));

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert an array to object in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869091/how-to-convert-an-array-to-object-in-php)

Comment: the question above is different problem and it just solve one level arrays.

Comment: Convet array to std class object $array = json_decode(json_encode($object), True);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i improvised another way to do so:

```
$ar=[
'a'=>[
        'field1'=>52,
        'field2'=>52,
        'field3'=>52,
         ],
'b'=>[
        'field1'=>52,
        'field2'=>52,
        'field3'=>52,
        ]
];

function ToObj($data) {
  if (gettype($data) == 'array')
    return (object)array_map("ToObj", $data);
  else
    return $data;
}
$ObjectResult = array_map("ToObj", $ar);
```