# PHP: return array values via -> (pointer)

Tags: php

I use below code to get outputs database:

```
$array = array();
while($row = ...){
   $array[] = $row;
}

return $array;
```

Now, i can get values:

```
foreach($array as $in){
   echo $in[title];
}
```

But i want get values by `->` :

```
foreach($array as $in){
   echo $in->title;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store objects during the `while()` loop.

Using MySQLi, with [`fetch_object()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php):

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    // here, $row is an object
    $array[] = $row;
}
```

Using PDO, with [`fetch()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php), and the `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` constant:

```
while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    // here, $row is an object
    $array[] = $row;
}
```

Then you could access using `->`:

```
foreach($array as $in){
   echo $in->title;
}
```

Comment: this is much better.+1

Comment: @Syscall, Thank you. Which is better in general?

Comment: @TeMe Between what and what? PDO and MySQLi or arrays and objects? Is mostly as you prefer, IMHO. Maybe it could depends of what you have to do with your data after that.

Comment: @Syscall Between arrays and objects

Comment: @TeMe As I said in my updated comment, it _could_ depends of what you have to do with your data after that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
$object = new stdClass();

foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
    $object->$key = $value;
}
```

Or refer to **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869091/how-to-convert-an-array-to-object-in-php)** answer