# Need help access like object in php

Tags: php

I have this `array`

```
$data = array(
        'employer' => $employer,
        'manager' => $manager
    );
```

my intention is access the array as an object, like: `$data->employer`.

How can i do that?

Comment: Cast it to an object? `$data = (object) array( ... )`

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/ReflectingEmbarrassedVisitor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert an array to object in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869091/how-to-convert-an-array-to-object-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can typecast an array to object like so:

```
<?php

$data = array(
    'employer' => "employer",
    'manager' => "manager "
);

$object = (object) $data;

var_dump($object->employer); // => "employer"
```

The returned value will be an instance of `\stdClass`, [as described in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php#language.types.object.casting).