# How can a function return an object?

Tags: php, function, object

I have a function which returns an array:

```
function myfunc(){
    return ["status" => true];
}
```

And here is the usage:

```
if ( myfunc()['status'] ){
    // do something
}
```

See? I have to get the status of `myfunc()` like this `myfunc()['status']`. All I'm trying to do is getting it like this `myfunc()->status`. Any idea how can I modify the function to get the status like an object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert an array to object in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869091/how-to-convert-an-array-to-object-in-php)

Comment: You can either create a class that has the `status` field, or only cast your array to `object`, like `$obj = (object)['status' => true];`

Answer (score 2):

Just cast the array into an object:

```
function myFunc() {
    return (object) ['status' => true];
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php