# Need to create object

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [download] => 8.63058 [date] => 2019 03 23 12:16 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [download] => 10.94184 [date] => 2019 03 23 12:17 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [download] => 11.37850 [date] => 2019 03 23 12:18 ) ) 


 Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [upload] => 2.95235 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [upload] => 2.87732 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [upload] => 3.58455 ) )
```

I need above mearge two arrays as below.

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [download] => 8.63058 [upload]=>2.95235 [date] => 2019 03 23 12:16 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [download] => 10.94184 [upload]=>2.87722 [date] => 2019 03 23 12:17 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [download] => 11.37850 [upload]=>3.58455 [date] => 2019 03 23 12:18 ) )
```

Comment: `json_decode(json_encode($arr), true);`

Comment: `(object)$array;`

Comment: Please make it readable, use https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert an array to object in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869091/how-to-convert-an-array-to-object-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

This will go over both arrays (they need to have the same keys!) and fetch all properties from the second array and write them into the object in array 1.

```
$arr1 = [ /* your objects */ ];
$arr2 = [ /* your objects */ ];

foreach ($arr1 as $index => $obj) {
    $vars = get_object_vars($arr2[$index]);

    foreach ($vars as $var => $value) {
        $obj->$var = $value;
    }
}
```

---

If it is just 'upload' you need from array 2, its even easier:

```
$arr1 = [ /* your objects */ ];
$arr2 = [ /* your objects */ ];

foreach ($arr1 as $index => $obj) {
    $obj->upload = $arr2[$index]->upload;
}
```

Comment: how do i create $arr1 and $arr2

Comment: If it works, consider upvoting and accepting my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
TRY THIS 

$array1 = json_decode(json_encode($arr1), true); // convert to array
$array2 = json_decode(json_encode($arr2), true); // convert to array

$arr_merged = array_merge($array1, $array2); // merge both arrays 

$arr_merged = json_decode(json_encode($arr_merged)); // to make it back into an object
```