# Laravel Loop Nested JSON

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

[Here is an image showing the json object being recieved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CCEQ.png)

I pefromed the following loop on the view but i am getting the following error.
**Trying to get property 'article' of non-object**

```
  @foreach ($news as $key => $value)
        {{$value->article}}
      @endforeach
```

Comment: Have you json_decode() it first?

Comment: yeah i have. i am passing it to the view as a json_decode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"->" just work on objects , if you are using an array shuld use "$value['article']" to get value

```
@foreach ($news['articles'] as $key => $value)
        {{$value['content']}}
@endforeach
```

also may your $value is an object but article key not exist on it.

[Convert Array to Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869091/how-to-convert-an-array-to-object-in-php)

Comment: Tried that and its not working. Getting------ Illegal string offset 'articles'

Comment: its happening because your $value is a string use {{$value}} to check it.

Comment: i have done that and its given me the following error --- htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: please check $news content with dd(); i dont know what is that content.
may screenshot be helpful

Comment: here is a screensheet after i dd($news) https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aftG9tHqX3xj19KS6xbiCR9_v-X8nv4I

Comment: Do you mind explaining your answer to me. Why the previous forloop method i use not work?

Comment: Because that loop returns 3 parameters ['status','resultcount','results' ] This is not what you need.
you should directly get $news['results']  to access its result array, and pass it to foreach