# How do I change my data accessing way from data[key] to data->key in laravel collection?

Tags: arrays, laravel, object, collections, collect

I got a data structure like below that is created by laravel collection put() function.

Code:

```
$array= collect();
$array->put($id, "1");
$array->put($name, "test");
```

Result:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "test"
}
```

How can I get the value with this syntax `$array->id` instead of this `$array['id']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this answers, https://stackoverflow.com/a/56565951/641611

```
$arr = ['id' => 3];
$arrToObject = (object) $arr;
echo $arrToObject->id;
```

Comment: You can read more about [casting to an object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php#language.types.object.casting) or just [type casting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) in general in PHP.