# I have an array and i need to change the array format

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array result like this

```
Array
(
    [e] => 6
    [i] => 5
    [s] => 4
    [n] => 0
    [t] => 0
)
```

And i need to change the array format to this,

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [type] => e
            [count] => 6
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [type] => i
            [count] => 5
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [type] => s
            [count] => 4
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
           [type] => n
           [count] => 0
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
           [type] => t
           [count] => 0
        )
)
```

Is there any way to change ?

Comment: May be this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869091/how-to-convert-an-array-to-object-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$newArray = [];
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    $obj = new stdClass;
    $obj->type = $k;
    $obj->count = $v;
    $newArray[] = $obj;
}
```