# convert every array inside an array to objects

Tags: php, arrays, object

im trying to work with Select2 with ajax as data source, and im getting the data alright but i need to convert the arrays inside my array to objs so Select2 can ''reproduce'' them as options.
What i have:

```
  Array
    (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => john
            [1] => johnjohn
        )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => john2
        [1] => johnjohn2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => john3
        [1] => johnjohnjohn3
    )
.....
)
```

what i need:

```
    {
  "results": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "text": "jhon",
      "text2": "jhonjhon"

    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "text": "jhon2",
      "text2": "jhon22"
    }
  ]
}
```

As said in the documention i need to make them objects:

> Select2 requires that each object contain an id and a text property. Additional parameters passed in with data objects will be included on the data objects that Select2 exposes.

I tried:
[How to convert an array to object in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869091/how-to-convert-an-array-to-object-in-php) and
[Convert Array to Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215737/convert-array-to-object) and i cant figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over the array, for each element create an associative array containing the values and push that onto the result array.

```
$objects = [];
foreach ($arrays as $i => $vals) {
    $objects[] = ['id' => $i+1, 'text' => $vals[0], 'text2' => $vals[1]];
}
```

Comment: thanks it work, but i forgot and i have a problem i need it like this: ````{
  "results": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "text": "Option 1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "text": "Option 2"
    }
  ],
  "pagination": {
    "more": true
  }
}```` how can i add the Result to it?

Comment: I don't see how that're related to the input you show. Please edit the question to clarify.

Comment: Show what the result should be with values like `johnjohn`

Comment: Its edited, sorry for the bad expose of the problem