# How can I serialize WhatsApp message payload to fetch the message body, phone_number_id, contact in Laravel php

Tags: php, laravel

```
{
  "field": "messages",
  "value": {
    "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
    "metadata": {
      "display_phone_number": "16505551111",
      "phone_number_id": "123456123"
    },
    "contacts": [
      {
        "profile": {
          "name": "test user name"
        },
        "wa_id": "16315551181"
      }
    ],
    "messages": [
      {
        "from": "16315551181",
        "id": "ABGGFlA5Fpa",
        "timestamp": "1504902988",
        "type": "text",
        "text": {
          "body": "this is a text message"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to parse json? `$obj = json_decode($json);` `$obj->value->metadata->phone_number_id`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to save the response to a variable and get the data from the array as follows

```
$message = $responce['value']['message'];
$phone_number = $responce['value']['metadata']['phone_number_id'];
$contact = $responce['value']['contacts'];
```

You can also decode the response first and then you can easily do the following

```
$res = json_decode($responce);
$message = $res->value->message;
$phone_number= $res->value->metadata->phone_number_id;
$contact = $res->value->contacts;
```

But if you want to convert the JSON you have to a Laravel object I recommend checking out the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1869091/how-to-convert-an-array-to-object-in-php).