# Change object type

Tags: php, codeigniter, object

I'm using CodeIgniter.

I have two Objects of type **UserLib** and **stdClass**.

When I do this: `$UserLib = $stdClass`, the properties os **UserLib** will receive the **stdClass** properties because they are the same.

The problem is that the object type is stdClass and I need it to be UserLib

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Type casting for user defined objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147109/type-casting-for-user-defined-objects)

Comment: thanks for the heads up Deminan ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would be best accomplished by making a function that takes transfers all the data you need from the stdClass to the UserLib:

```
function makeUserLib($user_lib, $std_class)
{
    $user_lib->myfirstvar = $std_class->myfirstvar;
    $user_lib->mysecondvar = $std_class->mysecondvar;
    etc...
}
```

Also, if you can edit your UserLib class, I'd suggest making this function a method in the class.