# How can Java from Kent Beck's book TDD by example be represented in PHP?

Tags: java, php, unit-testing, tdd, phpunit

I am teaching myself PHP as well as TDD (Using PHP and PHPUnit). I am working through the book [Test-driven Development by Example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321146530) by Kent Beck.

In Chapter 3, for example, He suggests this for the equality test:

```
public void testEquality() {
    assertTrue(new Dollar(5).equals(new Dollar(5)));
}
```

In the Dollar class he rewrites the equals method as such:

```
public boolean equals(Object object) {
   Dollar dollar = (Dollar) object;
   return amount == dollar.amount;
}
```

It probably does not help that I am new to PHP, but I am not sure how to translate that into PHP.

For the first function I tried:

```
public function testEquality(){
    $a = new Dollar(5);
    $this->assertTrue($a->equals($b = new Dollar(5)));
}
```

Is this the right track? As much as I know of PHP right now objects have to be assigned to a variable, correct?  Before that route I explored

```
$this->assertTrue(new Dollar(5)->equals(new Dollar(5)));
```

threw a syntax error.  Surprising as refactoring the earlier testMultiplication method with `$this->assertEquals(new Dollar(10), $five->times(2));` passed, however.

As far as the `equals` method is concerned, that's completely foreign to me, and I just don't know where to start.

How can I correctly reconstruct the above in PHP? If I can get a few right I think I can handle the rest of the examples.

As a side question, does anyone know if this Money example has been approached in PHP and is the code out there?

Comment: As far as the equals, I'm not sure how to read it and then rewrite it in PHP. `Dollar dollar = (Dollar) object` What is that actually saying? Here, for PHP, would I create a dollar object and then compare it to the object passed in the argument? Something like $d = new Dollar(); is_object($object)?  2 problems with that, my Dollar constructor requires in integer and I can tell if the argument is an object, but not that it is of type dollar. Also, casting (Dollar) as the Java does I do not know how to do in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is the following

```
public boolean equals(Object object) {
   Dollar dollar = (Dollar) object;
   return amount == dollar.amount;
}
```

And it means this (line for line)

1. define a new method called `equals` that will return either `true` or `false` and expects an object of type `Object` (in Java that means every object) as argument
2. convert the object of type `Object` to type `Dollar` [(wiki on type conversion)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion), now you are able to use the public methods and attributes of this object
3. compare the attribute `amount` from the current context with the one that comes from `dollar` (which comes from `object`)

You can now translate the method line by line to PHP [without the need of typecasting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147109/type-casting-for-user-defined-objects)

```
public function equals($object)
{
    return $this->amount == $object->amount;
}
```

It is possible to use a different method declaration:

```
public function equals(Dollar $object)
```

This way you can be sure only to compare two objects of the same type.

The usage is similar to the Java one as well:

```
$a = new Dollar(5);
$b = new Dollar(5);
if ($a->equals($b))
    print "TRUE";
else
    print "FALSE";
```

To learn more about object comparison in PHP, you better read the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php)