# Cast variable in Zend 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

This may be a stupid question, but I need to know how to cast a variable in zf2.

```
$var = (string) $id ;
```

How ca I do it with this kind of type :

```
\MediaLayer\Argument\SelectMediaArguments
```

This doesn't work:

```
$arg = (\MediaLayer\Argument\SelectMediaArguments) $var
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to type cast in php.

i could be wrong but i a, guesting that you want you IDE to recognize the $var az the selected class , in that case you need to use phpdoc block :

```
/* @var $var \MediaLayer\Argument\SelectMediaArguments */
$var = X;
```

if this is not what you want please be more clear because there is not object casting in php

also [Type casting for user defined objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147109/type-casting-for-user-defined-objects)