# Can I change object's type in php?

Tags: php, class, oop, object

I use `PDOStatement` object to fetch result of a query into an object of `NewOrder` class type.

```
$result = $pdo->query($strsql);
$result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'NewOrder');
$order = $result->fetch()
```

`NewOrder` is a base class that has children. I always need to instantiate a child rather than this base class `NewOrder` (it could be an abstract class but then the fetching wouldn't work). However, which child to instantiate can be determined based on value in `order_type` field of the `result`. After the `result` is fetched I have access to this value:

```
$orderType = $order->getOrderType();
```

Once I get this value, is it possible to change the type of `$order` object from `NewOrder` to one of its children (depending on the value `$orderType`)? The reason why I want to do it this way is because I want to avoid creating a new object and reassigning all attributes from object `$order` of `NewOrder` type to object `$order2` of `NewOrderChild` type.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot typecast objects in PHP. See answer for [Type casting for user defined objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1147377/4296151).

Maybe you want to have a look at [Doctrine 2 ORM](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html) which supports this type of mapping through [Single Table Inheritance](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance).