# How to assign ancestor to descendant type in PHP - class type casting

Tags: php, inheritance, casting, descendant

I am trying to assign an ancestor(A) to descendant(B) type variable and call descendant method on ancestor in PHP but I can't get it working.

```
class B extends A{
   public function c(){ echo 'B.c'}
}
```

I have tried:

1. Rewriting `B` constructor

   ```
   class B extends A{
       public function __construct($parent)
       {
           $this = $parent;
       }
       ...
   }
   ```

`$this` cannot be rewritten, so it's a no-go.

2. This thing I am forgetting how is it called

   ```
   function d(B $b){ 
       $b = new A(); 
       b.c();
   }
   ```
3. Explicit type casting

   ```
   function d(){
       $b = (B) new A();
       b.c();
   }
   ```

   Or

   ```
   function d(){ 
       $b = settype(new A(),'B');
       b.c()
   }
   ```

This doesn't work either as `settype` only allows certain types not other user defined object types.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php see examples :)

Comment: **call descendant method on ancestor in PHP** ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[All](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#50791) the [information](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1147109/699305) I've [seen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3243900/699305) suggests that there is no clean way to modify an object's type. (PHP merely fakes certain kinds of casting, e.g. there is an `(int)` operator but type `int` is unknown by itself.)

The approaches I've found are of two types:

1. Serialize your object, hack the string to modify its type, deserialize. (See [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#50791) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1147414/699305)-- equivalent). Or
2. Instantiate a new object and copy over all its properties. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4722587/699305))

I'd go with the second approach since you seem to be dealing with a known object hierarchy:

```
class B extends A {
    public function __construct(A $object) {
        foreach($object as $property => $value) {
            $this->$property = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

If you have some control over the creation of the original object, consider implementing a factory pattern so that you object is created with type `B` from the start.