# Create an inheritance table and how to get superclass ? Doctrine Symfony

Tags: symfony, inheritance, doctrine-orm

I've two entities: Act and Birth with Birth which extends Act like that

```
/**
* Act
*
* @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
*
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ActRepository")
*/
class Act
{
   /**
   * @var int
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   */
   private $id;

   /**
   * @var string
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="type", type="string", length=30, nullable=true)
   */
   private $type;
}


/**
* Birth
*
* @ORM\Table(name="birth")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\BirthRepository")
*/
class Birth extends Acte
{
   /**
   * @var int
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   */
   private $id;
}
```

And when I create a birth instance

```
new Birth();
```

I would like to recover the instance of its super class ie Act Entity !
I have to assign it to another class (Individual) with individual->setAct() and not individu->setBirth() ...

I do not know if it's possible but I want some advice for another approach 
Thanks !

Comment: so you want to make an instance of a class to something which it isn't?

Comment: 0
down vote
accept

From the birth instance so $birth = new Birth(), I want to recover the instance Act (the super birth class) so $act with a style thing $act = $birth->getSuperClass() or $birth->get(superclass::Act)...

Comment: please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147109/type-casting-for-user-defined-objects/1147377#1147377) why I don't think that's possible. and it sounds like bad design, too.

Comment: check this "solution" which tries to [cast an object into a parent class](https://gist.github.com/duaiwe/960035) - I won't propose it as an answer because it sounds too hacky to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Type casting for user defined objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147109/type-casting-for-user-defined-objects)

Comment: Have you try single table inheritance  from doctrine ? [Inheritance documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just do no redefine the $id in the child class, and declare the $id in Act protected.

Then

```
$birth = new Birth();
if($birth instanceof Act){
    // TRUE!
    // you could access $birth->type if it was public
}
```

Comment: Yes but I wanted to assign the instance Act generate with the instance of Birth to an individual like this: $ individu-> setAct (Act) $ act) and not $ individu-> setActe ($ birth)

Comment: Finally, I change my data model !